# Is there a way to specify the grid cache in grid gain to be partitioned across specific nodes?

Tags: datagrid, gridgain

In grid gain when I define a partitioned grid cache, is there any way to specify the cache to be partitioned only on some specfic nodes rather than on all the available nodes ( which happens by default )

Answer (score 0):

In GridGain every node starts up with a GridConfiguration object which is either created programmatically or from Spring XML configuration file. All you need to do is remove the specific cache from the configuration and it won't be initialized on that node.

Comment: Hi Dimitry, I am seeing the nodes on which the cache is not defined also sharing the data which is being inserted on other nodes ( on which the cache is initialized with partitioning and backup set to 1 ).I see the memory increase on a node even though it does not have the cache defined.

Comment: Also one more observation,  I have 5 nodes ( 2 of them have cache defined A with partitioning , backup set to 1 and the other 2 have cache defined B with partitioning , backup set to 1 ). What I see is if I insert the data in cache A, the 2 nodes which do not have the cache A defined are also sharing the data ... Since i see the memory increase on those nodes too..

Comment: @Tadaka I cannot reproduce this issue. I am pretty sure that there is something misconfigured in your environment. Please provide your configuration and I will take a look (you can use pastebin.com to paste your code or configuration)

Comment: <property name="cacheConfiguration">
            <list>  
                <bean parent="cache-template">
                    <property name="name" value="A"/>
                    <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
                    <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
                    <property name="distributionMode" value="PARTITIONED_ONLY"/>
                    <property name="backups" value="1"/>
                </bean>                 
            </list>
        </property>

Comment: <bean id="cache-template" abstract="true" class="org.gridgain.grid.cache.GridCacheConfiguration">
         <property name="startSize" value="5000"/>     
         <property name="preloadMode" value="SYNC"/>     
         <property name="writeSynchronizationMode" value="PRIMARY_SYNC"/>     
         <property name="queryIndexEnabled" value="true"/>
            </bean>

Comment: the above is for 2 nodes and the other 2 nodes also have the same config like above, but the cache name is B.  
I am seeing the data inserted into cache A is being partitioned into the nodes which have the cache B